# Calling the main method in jar file from php using php/java bridge

Tags: java, php, tomcat, executable-jar, php-java-bridge

I have installed the php/java bridge and and placed my jar file in the

```
\webapps\JavaBridge\WEB-INF\lib
```

Now I want to send a variable value from a php file to a parameter in a java method (which is in the jar file). Though I found some duplicates of this questions still I couldn't find the best solution. Below is what I have tried. But it gives me a `classNotFound` exception. And how to send a value from php and return value from jar?

```
<?php  
require_once("http://127.0.0.1:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");  
$System = java("java.lang.System");  
$myclass=java("classname.jarName");  
echo $System->getProperties();  
?>
```

Comment: "I found some duplicates"... How about you link to those duplicates and let us know why you're not happy with them so that we don't need to go through all of this again?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027443/how-to-call-jar-files-from-php

Comment: The above mentioned is a one question.but it still not working for me.I have done the same thing what he has done. FYI- i did not find how to pass and return variables.

Comment: as you point to that question, it's not "classname.jarName", it's rather "packagename.classname" where the packagename might contain a few dots. If you don't have a package, omit it (and the connecting dot). You'll find the package in the first line of your java class

Comment: yeh i dont have a package name.But if i put only the class name how will it identify the jar file?

Comment: Jar files in WEB-INF/lib will automatically be loaded by java appservers. If the class is in one of those files, it will be found, provided you give the name of an existing class and don't decorate it with other stuff (like "jarname")

Comment: Spelling, formatting